# How to extract <float> from Boost::Variant with Boost::Get?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I am using Boost::Variant in a schoolproject and struckels to extract "floats-types" from the Variant.

I have tried with std::string and float, and strings works fine.

```
    boost::variant<std::string, float> var1;
    var1 = 123.0F;
    var1 = "test";

    std::string s1 = boost::get<std::string>(var1);
    float f1 = boost::get<float>(var1);
```

But when the last line  is runned i get a boost::bad_get exception like it can't find the type float in the Variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's variant. It can handle only one value at the time. There is no float in variant when you call `boost::get`.

Comment: Ahh now I get it :D I through it was like a container. However, it is more like “var” in C#. A multi-type that can take different types. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ChristofferG container is for example boost::tuple.

Comment: I show both boost::tuple and boost::fusion::map in my answer, for inspiration

Comment: @ChristofferG, `var` is like `auto`, not a variant.

Answer (score 2):

What you'd expect is more like a tuple or a fusion map:

## Tuple

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc55cbc0c23f614d)**</kbd>

```
boost::tuple<std::string, float> var1 = boost::make_tuple("test", 123.0f);

std::string s1 = boost::get<0>(var1);
float f1       = boost::get<1>(var1);
```

## Fusion Map

<kbd>**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/076877176336a502)**</kbd>

```
map<
     pair<struct name_tag, std::string>, 
     pair<struct value_tag, float>
> var1 = make_map<name_tag, value_tag>("test", 123.0f);

std::string s1 = at_key<name_tag>(var1);
float f1       = at_key<value_tag>(var1);
```

Comment: To get a bit closer with the tuple, now in C++14, you can do `std::get<float>(var1);` with the standard tuple.

Comment: @chris Would you  believe it, I overlooked this change in c++14 o.O

Comment: As this was a school assignment where I was forced to use boost::variant. However, I appreciate your suggestion with tuple or fusion map. Thanks a lot! I am sure this will come handy later in my work ;)

Comment: But in that case they will **not** have required you to get a float out if the stored kind was string :)